# DialogFragment - reference from db to MainActivity Android Studio

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

In my database when a condition is fulfilles  i'd like to appear a AlertDialog popup. I've tried to do it in two ways, like this

**dataBaseHandler**

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
 result = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COUPONS_TIMES_TO_USE))
           -c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COUPONS_TIMES_USED));
if (result < 4) {
    MainActivity alert = new MainActivity();
    alert.showAlert();
 }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public void showAlert() {

AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
myAlert.setMessage("Text").create() 
myAlert.show();

}
```

There's no red errors in the code but when a condition is fulfilled during using the application, critical error appears on the screen. Here's what console says

```
D/QUERY: UPDATE coupons SET times_used = times_used + 1  WHERE id=1
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with 
uncaught exception(group=0xa4ccfb20)

[10-17 06:13:14.364  1579: 1724 D/]
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb9986d90, tid 1724
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: promocje, PID: 2744 java.lang.NullPointerException 

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo
(ContextWrapper.java:152)
at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:103)
at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:143)
at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:360)
at promocje.MainActivity.showAlert(MainActivity.java:164)    
at promocje.db.engine.DatabaseHandler.useCoupon
(DatabaseHandler.java:889)
at promocje.adapter.CouponListAdapter.useCoupon
(CouponListAdapter.java:166)
at promocje.adapter.CouponListAdapter$1$1.onFinish
(CouponListAdapter.java:144)
at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:118)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Application terminated.
```

I have tried also to this around in **alternate way**

**dataBaseHandler**

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
 result = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COUPONS_TIMES_TO_USE)) 
           - c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COUPONS_TIMES_USED));
if (result < 4) {
    PopUpFragment popup = new PopUpFragment();
    popup.show(FragmentManager manager, String tag);
}
```

**New java file with Dialog Fragment**

```
public class PopUpFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("I'm a PopUp")
            .setPositiveButton("Button 1", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // POSITIVE BUTTON
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Delete me", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                }
            });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
 }
}
```

Here i've got some problems with parameters in .show() method.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post your exception or critial error

Comment: First think I think of when you are dealing with UI and database issues is are you calling .show() on your UI thread or a background one, but would need to see more of your code to know.

Comment: I've edited the post with what console's shows after crash, take a look please